# How to create response assertion in beanshell at jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

There may be mistranslations because i'm using a translator.

i want to create response assertion in beanshell

script content is postrequest site and get responsedata

but this request usually fail so i want to check everytime with response assertion

i want to check make response assertion in jmeter beanshell

Whether the request is successful or not, I want to create a response assertion in beanshell.

can i help?

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(requestURL);

postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonMessage));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer sbRes = new StringBuffer();
    while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sbRes.append(inputLine);
                }
        reader.close();

String trans = sbRes.toString();
Boolean checkResult = trans.contains("result\":0");
if(checkResult==true){
         //** i want create response assertion here **
}
else{
        // **i want create response assertion here  **
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your code you're just sending 10 consecutive HTTP requests so it can be easily substituted with normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion), there is no need to go for scripting there

Whatever:

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.
2. You have `SampleResult` pre-defined variable which can be used for controlling:

   [image]

   - whether the sampler is successful or not via [SampleResult.setSuccessful()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSuccessful-boolean-) function
   - setting response code via [Sampleresult.setResponseCode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseCode-java.lang.String-) function
   - setting response message via [SampleResult.setResponseMessage()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseMessage-java.lang.String-) function

Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) to learn more about above and other JMeter API shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements